# autocomplete textview error

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

I am currently creating a autocomplete textview which uses data from the contacts. I cant seem get to fix the error on the last line

```
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    nameList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    while (cur.moveToNext())
    {
        nameList.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
        nameList.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
    }

    phonenumber =(AutoCompleteTextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tosend1);
```

the error line is this:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = newArrayAdapter <String>(this,R.layout.list_item2,nameList);
```

What seems to be the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *really* helps to see the logcat errors but I found a couple mistakes and I can only guess at the rest:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
        new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, 
        null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    list.add(cursor.getString(nameColumn) + ": " + cursor.getString(numberColumn));
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

Voila, every name in your and number in your contacts.